# QGIS LTS broken in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I recently did an `sudo apt dist-upgrade` on two Ubuntu 16.04 computers. I didn't pay especially close attention to the messages and now QGIS is gone. So I do
`sudo apt install qgis` and I get `qgis : Depends: python-qgis (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed`

Any idea where my problem might be?

Answer (score 6):

Currently there is a bug in the Ubuntugis unstable package of qgis 2.14.17, see https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16975

You can wait until that is fixed, or change your sources.list to `deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr xenial main` for the official QGIS download site that has already been fixed.

---

**Update**

The qgis package in the Ubuntugis unstable ppa has been updated, so you can now use the ppa with or without `http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr xenial main`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar happened with 2.18 from the QGIS repo with dependencies from the UbuntuGIS repo. It has since been fixed (last 24 hrs), at least for 2.18. I'd expect a fix for 2.14 won't be far off.

What repo are you installing QGIS from?

Comment: The qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr package has already been fixed too. The damaged package is from the ubuntugis unstable ppa: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+sourcepub/8143543/+listing-archive-extra

Comment: @Tim - I'm using ubuntugis-unstable so my problem is what AndreJ has noted.